# Calculus: derivative of logarithm with respect to logarithm

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have this expression:
$$ \dfrac{d\ln\left(\dfrac{x_2}{x_1}\right)}{d\ln(\theta)} $$
That I’m hoping to get some help solving,

Where $\ln\left(\dfrac{x_2}{x_1}\right)= \ln\left(\dfrac{1-a}{a}\right)+\ln(\theta)$

and

$\theta= \dfrac{a}{1-a} \cdot \dfrac{x_2}{x_1}$

My confusion stems from having a derivative with ln in both the numerator and denominator and I’m not sure how to correctly proceed. I know the answer is $1$, however, I’m more interested in knowing the technique to get there. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Set $u=\ln\theta$; then it's $\dfrac d{du}\left(\ln\frac{1-a}a+u\right)$

Comment: Um... which are constants and which are variables.  If $x_1,x_2$ are constant the $\frac {d\ln x2/x1}{d\ln \theta} = 0$.  But if $x_1,x_2$ are some variables and $a$ is constant then $\frac {d\ln x2/x1}{d\ln \theta} = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. In the general form, you can find a derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to $g(x)$  ,in other hand $\frac{d(f(x))}{d(g(x))}$ by dividing $f,g$ to $dx$ like below
$$\frac{d(f(x))}{d(g(x))}=\frac{\frac{d(f(x))}{dx}}{\frac{d(g(x))}{dx}}=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
in your case this can be show
$$\frac{d\ln(x2/x1)}{d\ln(\theta)}=\frac{\frac{d \ln(x2/x1)}{d\theta}}{\frac{d\ln \theta}{d\theta}}=\\\frac{\dfrac{d(\ln(\frac{1-a}{a})+\ln(\theta))}{d\theta}}{\dfrac{d\ln \theta}{d\theta}}=\frac{0+1\over \theta}{1\over \theta}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{d(C+\ln \theta)}{d\ln \theta}==\frac{d(C+z)}{dz}=1.$$